Is $\sqrt{x}$ continuous at $x=0$ even though the left-hand limit does not exist?
I know this question has been asked and answered before and I found this answer Limit of $\sqrt x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ helpful, in particular the response from @pie, and I am convinced that $f(x)=\sqrt(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. However, this raises another question about how we define one-sided limits.
I have always understood that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ if and only if  $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$. However, when $f(x)=\sqrt(x)$, is $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x)$ defined?
Based on @pie's response, we can define the left-hand limit as such:
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$. For a function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$, a real number $L$ is said to be a limit of $f$ at $c$ if, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in A$ and $0<c-x<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.
In the case $f(x)=\sqrt(x)$ and $A=[0,\infty)$, $c=0$ and $L=0$ it is vacuously true that given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in A$ and $0<c-x<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ as there are no $x\in A$ such that $0<c-x<\delta$ as this requires $x<0$, so it appears by this definition that  $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x)=0$. But the same is true when $L=1$ or any other real number, so the left-hand limit is not unique.
I suppose we could change the definition to stipulate that the set $(x \in A : 0<c-x<\delta)$ is non-empty, but then we conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x)=0$ does not exist, which contradicts $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ if and only if  $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$.
The problem here presumably is the fact that zero is boundary point of the domain? It appears that if $c$ (in the closure of $A$) is not a boundary point then it is true that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ if and only if  $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$ exist and $\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$, but if $c$ is a boundary point of $A$ then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^{-}} f(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^{+}} f(x)$, whichever exists, but this seems a bit ad hoc?
Also, what about the case when $A$ is a single real number (eg. $f : \{0\}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x$). Does $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$ but neither the left-hand nor right-hand limit exist?

Yes, it will be continuous at zero. (You're overthinking it.) The reason is that the epsilon condition need not be satisfied on inputs which do not exist in the domain $[0,\infty).$ Does this help?

Your answer depends on the definition.  State the exact definition of "continuous" to be used.

@GEdgar Judging by his definition of “left-hand limit” as well OPs fixation on limits, would it not be reasonable to assume his definition involves showing $f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)?$ (So his definition of continuity would just be the standard epsilon-delta definition, again judging by his definition of limit.)

This is a very FAQ. https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=one-sided+limit+definition We should probably close as a duplicate, but which target to choose?

Yes, sorry, I'm defining continuous as $f(c) = \lim_{x \to c}f(x)$. Really, the question is whether  $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt(x)$ exists. I'm happy that it does, using the definition on the post I link to, but if our definition requires that $c \in I$ where $I$ is some open set and $I\setminus {0}$ is a subset of the domain then I see that the limit does not exist, as there is no such $I$.

My problem is that it appears that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\sqrt{x}$ does not exist and so $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}\neq\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\sqrt{x}=0$.

All of these comments depend on the definition.  Just saying "usual epsilon-delta definition" isn't enough.  We need to know exactly what the quantifiers are.

The definition of the left-hand limit I am using is this: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$. For a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, a real number $L$ is a left-hand limit of $f$ at $c$ if and only, given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in A$ and $0<c-x<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

The definition of the limit I am using is this: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be a limit point of $A$. For a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, a real number $L$ is a limit of $f$ at $c$ if and only, given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

By my definitions, $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\sqrt{x}$ is not unique. If in the definition of the left-hand limit we insist that $c$ is a limit point of $A\cap(-\infty,c)$ then $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\sqrt{x}$ does not exist. Either way $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}\neq\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\sqrt{x}$. Is the correct statement, according to my defintions, that, if $c$ is not a boundary point of $A$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=L$?

In Germany , I learnt it different to the "official" definition. We did not consider this function continuous since it is not defined for $x<0$. For the "official" definition , this is irrelevant and therefore this function is considered to be continuous. I am glad to have learnt the officially wrong way since it describes more intuitive when a function is continous. We only would have called this "right-continous".

Yes, and right-differentiable. I guess my question is which is the authoritative epsilon-delta definition that I should use? I know that there is not one “correct” definition, but which is the most widely accepted definition?

Welcome to MSE! <> The definition in your comment would best be edited into the question body; otherwise, future passersby must read the comments to understand the question. <> Given the definition: "Yes, the limit exists." Your understanding about one-sided limits turns out not to apply here, i.e., is not equivalent to the definition. <> You haven't given your definition of continuity but in the circumstances it would be perverse not to call the square root continuous at $0$.
